# Unable to import JAR files?

Tags: java

I need a particular JAR file, fo execute a code. I am able to run the code In eclipse by adding the JAR file to libraries.

But when I run he code from cmd prompt I get error saying unable to import javax.jms(the jar file).

```
C:\tibco\ems\8.5\samples\java\JNDI>javac tibjmsJNDIFT.java
tibjmsJNDIFT.java:43: error: package javax.jms does not exist
import javax.jms.*;
^
tibjmsJNDIFT.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
                        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                        ^
  symbol:   class ConnectionFactory
  location: class tibjmsJNDIFT
tibjmsJNDIFT.java:109: error: cannot find symbol
                        (ConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup(factory[j]);
                         ^
  symbol:   class ConnectionFactory
  location: class tibjmsJNDIFT
3 errors

C:\tibco\ems\8.5\samples\java\JNDI>
```

Comment: I think you are confusing your terminology here.  There is no such thing as a "JRE file".  Are you talking about a JAR file perhaps?   Also, a message about being "unable to import" something sounds like a compilation error not an error you get when you run something.

Comment: yes, my mistake

Comment: It would be best to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem and the exact error message.

Comment: try putting import file in same dir as running code file.

Comment: You have to add `JAR` files to class path. Like this `javac -cp SOME_DIR/FILE.jar tibjmsJNDIFT.java`. Then, for running, you have to point to both: JAR location and your compile classes: `java -cp SOME_DIR/FILE.jar:target tibjmsJNDIFT`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "-cp" or "-classpath" option:

```
javac -cp ".:/path/to/jms.jar:/path/to/any-other.jar" tibjmsJNDIFT.java
```

On Windows OS you might have to use "semicolons" (;) instead of "colons" (:)